# How can I replace outer object with an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I'm trying to make a graph. S I need to send an ajax request, select some rows from database, then return the result. I did it. And here is the output:

```
success : function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

[image]

To make that graph, I need to convert my current output to this structure: *(this structure is the one I should pass it to the library which draws the graph)*

```
  var json = [
    {
      "adjacencies": [
        {
          "nodeTo": "graphnode15", 
          "nodeFrom": "graphnode0", 
          "data": {}
        }, 
        {
          "nodeTo": "graphnode16", 
          "nodeFrom": "graphnode0", 
          "data": {}
        }, 
        {
          "nodeTo": "graphnode17", 
          "nodeFrom": "graphnode0", 
          "data": {}
        }
      ], 
      "data": {
        "$color": "#83548B", 
        "$type": "circle"
      }, 
      "id": "12", 
      "name": "sajad"
    }
  ];
```

I've tested all of these:

- `console.log(data);`
- `console.log([data]);`
- `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));`
- `console.log("["+JSON.stringify(data)+"]");`

But none of them isn't expected structure for the library which draws the graph. Anyway, Does anybody know how can I make expected structure?

Comment: @Kenny Doesn't work https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZL8T.png

Comment: My bad its JSON in capital, not Json

Comment: @Kenny It throws this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCfYT.png

Comment: What response you get from the ajax request?

Comment: @Kenny here is the response https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vsp7q.png

Comment: Post raw response that you are getting. In Dev tools, Network tab you can find your ajax call.

Comment: If its type is object then [data], should have to work, just check your data object

Comment: I agree that that `[data]` should work. Can you post a snippet online so can we copy/paste your data object?

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse(data)` will do this.

Try:

```
json =[]

json.push(data)
```

send this json to the graph

Comment: Not a Json, JSON.

Comment: Check your response has valid JSON format. If not, it throws exception.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this should work

```
success : function (data) {
    var json = [JSON.parse(data)];
    console.log(json);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, make sure the data return a raw JSON format.. try check it with alert(data);